# asp.net core can't get xml data from url

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

I'm using Amazon API to generate request for ItemLookup. After signing the request I got a url:

http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=[AccessKey]&AssociateTag=[AssociateTag]&ItemId=B06XBCY6DW&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes%2COffers%2CReviews&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2050-02-13T12:00:00Z&Version=2016-02-12&Signature=[Signature]

Which I use in browser and I can see nice xml with item's data, but When I try to get that data with c# I get error

> The Uri parameter must be a file system relative or absolute path.

The method I'm using to get data is:

```
var itemXml = XElement.Load(url);
```

How can I get that xml in c#??

Comment: The url is a String I guess? If so, the documentation suggests it should be a file which I interpret as it should be local on your own pc. not sure though
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.load(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And a link with an example
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307643/how-to-read-xml-data-from-a-url-by-using-visual-c

Comment: @GertKommer yes my url is string, but your given example does not work in asp.net core

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is nothing .net core specific.

`XElement.Load` accepts a string - which, if you look at the intellisense states:

> Loads an XElement from a file.

This isn't what you want. It's trying to resolve the URI from the filesystem.

You'll need to read the URL content into a Stream.

Try the following

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var result = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;

var stream = result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

var itemXml = XElement.Load(stream);
```

Note I've used `.Result` - I would recommend instead using `await` (async/await) pattern

Comment: Thank´s you save me :)